Circular dependency between the following tasks (Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 )
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:MapSupport:extractDeepLinksLive_Release
\--- :MapSupport:fabricGenerateResourcesLive_Release
     \--- :MapSupport:processLive_ReleaseManifest
          \--- :MapSupport:processLive_ReleaseMainManifest
               \--- :MapSupport:extractDeepLinksLive_Release (*)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 1s

I have updated my Android Studio to latest Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 and could not launch my application neither I am able to create build. Any help please.
Attaching Gradle dependencies here -:
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':library-pull-to-refresh')
    implementation project(':view-pager-strip_lib')
    implementation project(path: ':oidclib')
    //compile 'com.cesards.android:cropimageview:1.0.2.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {//2.6.1
        transitive = true
    }
    //compile 'com.haozhang.libary:android-slanted-textview:1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.1.11') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' //1.0.1   1.0.3
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'///11.0.4' new 16.0.1
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    //fixme it is of no use I think verify 15.0.1
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'//gcm removed and firebase core and fcm included..
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0' ///15.0.1
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    ///implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' //1.0.1
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
    ///implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.21.0' //delete it when done
    /*compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'*/

//    implementation 'com.github.dewinjm:monthyear-picker:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


    //////////

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    // circle menu
    implementation 'com.ramotion.circlemenu:circle-menu:0.3.2'

    //camerax
    def camerax_version = "1.1.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"

    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"

    //loading
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'

    //coroutine
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'

   
     //Retrofit
    //implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    //implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
    //implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'


    //view model
    //val lifecycle_version = "2.6.0-alpha01"
    //val arch_version = "2.1.0"


    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.0")
    //implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-*:2.5.0")
    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.0")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.0")
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0")

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //pref datastore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

    //azure store sdk for blob

    //implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:2.0.0@aar'
    //azure auth
    //implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:3.0.+'
    //implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.14.1'
    //implementation("com.azure.android:azure-communication-chat:2.0.0")
    //implementation ('com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-keys:4.4.6')
    /*implementation 'com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-keys:4.0.0'
     implementation ('com.azure:azure-core'){
         version{
             strictly("1.11.0")
         }
         force(true)
     }
     implementation ('com.azure:azure-identity'){
         version{
             strictly("1.0.0")
         }
         force(true)
     }
     //implementation group: 'javax.xml.stream', name: 'stax-api', version: '1.0-2'

     implementation ('javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.5-5'){
         force(true)
     }*/

}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' /// added for firebase

